# parser for vstest.console in Bamboo

Tags: mstest, bamboo, vstest.console.exe

We are having to use the command configuration (to be able to specify the runsettings file that I want to use at the time of running the job) for vstest.console. But now it does not create the results within bamboo. like the vstest.console bamboo task does.

First question, does the mstest parser create that kind of results? Is there a way to do this after running the command prompt. Also, since they both create trx files, can I use mstest parser for the trx created by vstest.console?

Second question, I don't see in my log that it kicked off that step. Is there anything special I need to do to have it kicked off? Especially if the previous step fails?

Also, the .trx logger setting is not renaming the trx to my TestResult.trx file name.

I looked in the list of apps to see if there is a vstest.console version of the parser, there is not. We are using version 6.6.3 ..so we are a bit behind but not sure if this means anything with the parser.

Answer (score 0):

Must have had to do a reboot. I don't know why, but I came back in after the weekend, and the servers have been rebooted, and with no change to what I said above, the results are showing up as expected.